# pandas set value in column based on another dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine I have two pandas data frame as:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = {'y1': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
df2 = {'y2': [3, 1, 2, 6]}
```

What I want is if a value in y2 is greater than the value in y1, I want to set `df2['y2']` to the corresponding `df['y1']`. When I try selecting the corresponding columns like:

```
df2[df2['y2'] > df1['y1']]
```

This is returns `True` rather than the index. I was hoping to do something like:

```
df2[df2['y2'] > df1['y1']]['y2'] = df1['y1']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [233]: import numpy as np

In [234]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'y1': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
In [236]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'y2': [3, 1, 2, 6]})

In [242]: df2['y2'] = np.where(df2.y2.gt(df1.y1), df1.y1, df2.y2)

In [243]: df2
Out[243]: 
   y2
0   1
1   1
2   2
3   4
```

Answer (score 2):

If same index in both DataFrames:

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df2.loc[df2['y2'] > df1['y1'], 'y2'] = df1['y1'] 
print (df2)
   y2
0   1
1   1
2   2
3   4
```

Or[`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html), [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df2['y2'] = df1['y1'].where(df2['y2'].gt(df1['y1']), df2['y2'])
df2['y2'] = df2['y2'].mask(df2['y2'].gt(df1['y1']), df1['y1'])
print (df2)
   y2
0   1
1   1
2   2
3   4
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `np.minimum`

Maintain all of existing `df2` but with updated column values in `'y2'`

```
df2.assign(y2=np.minimum(df1.y1, df2.y2))

   y2
0   1
1   1
2   2
3   4
```

Or just a new dataframe with one column

```
pd.DataFrame({'y2': np.minimum(df1.y1, df2.y2)})

   y2
0   1
1   1
2   2
3   4
```